# invoking auto updater from launcher - Install4J

Tags: install4j

I'm trying to integrate an automatic update before the launch of my Java application without adding code to my application. If I read the documentation [here](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/concepts/autoUpdate.html) (Section "Quick Start") correctly, this should be possible with the application template *update downloader with silent version check*. Yet, after following the docs, the updater itself is working just fine, but it is for some reason not invoked at application startup.

[launcher integration configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2qX3.jpg)

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT 1:
Maybe this is relevant: the launcher is a .exe file that is generated by the application itself, and not a generated launcher by install4j

Comment: Are you sure it is not invoked? Silent version check means that if there is no new version in updates.xml, you will not see anything. To check, add an empty form screen after the startup node of the update downloader, this will be displayed in any case. You can then check the log file in the %TEMP% directory to see if there was a problem with the download of the updates.xml file.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain it is not invoked. Invoking the updater manually (by calling autoUpdater.exe in the .install4j folder) the update works. If the webserver is disabled an error log in %TEMP% appears. Nothing of the sort when the application is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatic launcher integration only works for generated launcher executables. For external launcher executables you have to start the update downloader with the API. On the "Launcher integration" tab for the update downloader, click in the "Start integration wizard" button to get a corresponding code snippet. This requires that you add the install4j runtime to the compilation classpath (but not to the distribution), for more information see

https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/api/